# iPhone App to transfer message over bluetooth but device is not getting connected

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit, ios4, gksession

I am working on this iPhone app with which you can send message to other connected device. I have gone through following tutorial

http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/

Everything seems to be fine. No memory leaks or anything like that. Now I installed this application on iPad and iTouch. iPad is running 4.3.5 and iTouch is running 4.2.1. I am using X Code 4.0 with iOS 4.3 as base sdk. I set my targets to 4.0 in X Code for above project (like Target->Messenger->summary->deployment target->4.0) similarly for project.

Now when I run application and try to connect it with other device, it shows only looking for nearby iOS devices and nothing happens further. But when I set deployment target to 4.3 and install same app on iPad, that iPad can detect iTouch but not able to connect it.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to deal with it ?

Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u try using Xcode Simulator to connect your iPod Touch by Blue Tooth?
Then it can make more sure that your programming run correctly.

Comment: No. I have not. I am not sure whether simulator allows it or not.

Comment: ya It does... But I still dont understand why its not allowing iPad and iTouch Connections.

Comment: Yes it is possible to test simulator with device